# Como hacer una transaccion en C# utilizando las variables que estan dentro del using()

Tags: c#, tablas, visual

tengo inconveniente con una trasaccion con c#, en NCAPAS les explico:
tengo 2 tablas tingreso y tdetalleingreso con sus id autoincrementable, al guardarse el idingreso se captura y se guarda en la table tdetalleingreso.

En la clase IngresoDatos
el problema  lo tengo aqui porque no puedo pasarle la varialbe command y transaccion, me muestra el mensaje no se pude pasar como referencia o salida ya que es esta dentro using

```
result = det.cd_insertarDetalleIngreso(det, ref command, ref transaction);
```

quise instanciarla de nuevo en otras varialbes de esta manera y se quitan los errores, cuando ejecuto y doy guardar dice que sql no acepta transacciones paralelas

```
//SqlConnection sqlcon= new SqlConnection();
//1   sqlcon= connection;
// SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
// SqlTransaction sqltra = sqlcon.BeginTransaction();
//1 sqlcmd.Connection = sqlcon;
//1 sqlcmd.Transaction = transaction;
```

al pasarle las variables command y transacciono, pasa el idingreso a la clase Detalleingreso y guarda
segun asi creo  que seria. talves me hechan una mano en el codigo como solucionarlo.

AL FINAL tengo el codigo de las clase que si funciona la transaccion y guarda en la base de datos en sus respectivas tablas todo lo hace bien.
quiero hacerlo conservando la estructura donde utilizo el using(),me siento mas comodo lo veo mas ordenado  de esta forma. por eso solicito de su conocimientos

saludos

```
public class IngresoDatos
{
    private int idingreso;
    private int idempleado;
    private int idproveedor;
    private DateTime fecha;
    private int tipocomprobante;
    private string comprobante;
    private int iva;
    private string estado;

    public int Idingreso
    {
        get { return idingreso; }
        set { idingreso = value; }
    }

    public int Idempleado
    {
        get { return idempleado; }
        set { idempleado = value; }
    }

    public int Idproveedor
    {
        get { return idproveedor; }
        set { idproveedor = value; }
    }

    public DateTime Fecha
    {
        get { return fecha; }
        set { fecha = value; }
    }

    public int Tipocomprobante
    {
        get { return tipocomprobante; }
        set { tipocomprobante = value; }
    }

    public string Comprobante
    {
        get { return comprobante; }
        set { comprobante = value; }
    }

    public int Iva
    {
        get { return iva; }
        set { iva = value; }
    }

    public string Estado
    {
        get { return estado; }
        set { estado = value; }
    }

    public IngresoDatos(int idingreso, int idempleado, int idproveedor, DateTime fecha,
        int tipocomprobante, string comprobante, int iva, string estado)
    {
        this.Idingreso = idingreso;
        this.Idempleado = idempleado;
        this.Idproveedor = idproveedor;
        this.Fecha = fecha;
        this.Tipocomprobante = tipocomprobante;
        this.Comprobante = comprobante;
        this.Iva = iva;
        this.Estado = estado;
    }
    //CONSTRUCTOR
    public IngresoDatos()
    { }

    /****************************************
              MEDTODO INSERTAR INGRESO 
    *****************************************/
    public string cd_insertarIngreso(IngresoDatos Ingreso, List<DetalleIngresoDatos> Detalle)
    {

        using (var connection = ConnectionToSql.getConnection())
        {
            connection.Open();
            string result = "";
            
            using ( SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction() )
            {
                using (var command = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    command.Connection = connection;
                    command.Transaction = transaction;

                    
                   //SqlConnection sqlcon= new SqlConnection();
                   //2 sqlcon = command.Connection;
                 //1   sqlcon= connection;

                   // SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();

                  // SqlTransaction sqltra = sqlcon.BeginTransaction();
                   //2 sqltra = command.Transaction;

                    //1 sqlcmd.Connection = sqlcon;
                    //1 sqlcmd.Transaction = transaction;

                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tingreso (idempleado, idproveedor, fecha, tipocomprobante, comprobante, iva, estado) " +
                    "VALUES (@idempleado,@idproveedor,@fecha,@tipocomprobante,@comprobante,@iva,@estado) SET @idIngreso=@@IDENTITY;";

                    SqlParameter ParIdingreso = new SqlParameter();
                    ParIdingreso.ParameterName = "@idIngreso";
                    ParIdingreso.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
                    ParIdingreso.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    command.Parameters.Add(ParIdingreso);
                    try
                    {

                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idempleado", idempleado);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idproveedor", idproveedor);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha", fecha);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipocomprobante", tipocomprobante);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comprobante", comprobante);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iva", iva);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@estado", estado);
                        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                        result = command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1 ? "OK" : "UBRO ingresodatos ERROR";

                        if (result.Equals("OK"))
                        {
                            //Obtener el código del ingreso generado
                            Idingreso = Convert.ToInt32(command.Parameters["@idIngreso"].Value);
                            foreach (DetalleIngresoDatos det in Detalle)
                            {
                                det.Idingreso = Idingreso;
                                //Llamar al método insertar de la clase DDetalle_Ingreso
                                result = det.cd_insertarDetalleIngreso(det, ref command, ref transaction);
                                if (!result.Equals("OK"))
                                {
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (result.Equals("OK"))
                        {
                            transaction.Commit();
                        }
                 
                    }

                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        transaction.Rollback();
                        result = ex.Message;
                    }
                    return result;

                }

            }

        }
    }




   public class DetalleIngresoDatos 
    {

        private int idingreso;
        private int idarticulo;

        public int Idingreso
        {
            get { return idingreso; }
            set { idingreso = value; }
        }

        public int Idarticulo
        {
            get { return idarticulo; }
            set { idarticulo = value; }
        }
        private int preciocompra;

        public int Preciocompra
        {
            get { return preciocompra; }
            set { preciocompra = value; }
        }
        private int precioventa;

        public int Precioventa
        {
            get { return precioventa; }
            set { precioventa = value; }
        }
        private int stockinicial;

        public int Stockinicial
        {
            get { return stockinicial; }
            set { stockinicial = value; }
        }
        private int stockactual;

        public int Stockactual
        {
            get { return stockactual; }
            set { stockactual = value; }
        }
        private DateTime fechaproduccion;

        public DateTime Fechaproduccion
        {
            get { return fechaproduccion; }
            set { fechaproduccion = value; }
        }
        private DateTime fechavencimiento;

        public DateTime Fechavencimiento
        {
            get { return fechavencimiento; }
            set { fechavencimiento = value; }
        }

      
        public DetalleIngresoDatos(int idingreso, int idarticulo, int preciocompra, int precioventa, int stockinicial, int stockactual, DateTime fechaproduccion, DateTime fechavencimiento)
        {
            this.idingreso = idingreso;
            this.idarticulo = idarticulo;
            this.preciocompra = preciocompra;
            this.precioventa = precioventa;
            this.stockinicial = stockinicial;
            this.stockactual = stockactual;
            this.fechaproduccion = fechaproduccion;
            this.fechavencimiento = fechavencimiento;
        }

        public DetalleIngresoDatos()
        {
        }
        public IEnumerable<DetalleIngresoDatos> a;

   
        /****************************************
             MEDTODO INSERTAR DETALLE INGRESO 
        *****************************************/
        public string cd_insertarDetalleIngreso(DetalleIngresoDatos DIDatos, ref SqlConnection SqlCon, ref SqlTransaction SqlTra)
        {
          
            using (var connection = ConnectionToSql.getConnection())
            {
                connection.Open();
                string a = "";
                using (SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    using (var command = new SqlCommand())
                    {
                        command.Connection = connection;
                        command.Transaction = transaction;

                        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tdetalleingreso (idingreso,idarticulo,preciocompra,precioventa,stockinicial,stockactual,fechaproduccion,fechavencimiento) " +
                          "VALUES (@idingreso,@idarticulo,@preciocompra,@precioventa,@stockinicial,@stockactual,@fechaproduccion,@fechavencimiento)";
                           
                        try
                        {
                            SqlParameter ParIddetalle_Ingreso = new SqlParameter();
                            ParIddetalle_Ingreso.ParameterName = "@idDetalleIngreso";
                            ParIddetalle_Ingreso.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
                            ParIddetalle_Ingreso.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                            command.Parameters.Add(ParIddetalle_Ingreso);

                            foreach (var item in a)
                            {
                               
                                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idingreso", idingreso);
                                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idarticulo", idarticulo);
                                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@preciocompra", preciocompra);
                                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@precioventa", precioventa);
                                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stockinicial", stockinicial);
                                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stockactual", stockactual);
                                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fechaproduccion", fechaproduccion);
                                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fechavencimiento", fechavencimiento);
                                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                                a = command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1 ? "OK" : " ERROR detalleIngreso";

                                if (a.Equals("OK"))
                                {
                                    transaction.Commit();
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            transaction.Rollback();
                            a = ex.Message;
                            connection.Close();
                            throw;
                        }

                        return a;
                    }
                }
            }
        }}}
```

DE ESTA MANERA SI FUNCIONA

```
/****************************************
      MEDTODO INSERTAR DETALLE INGRESO 
*****************************************/
        public string cd_insertarDetalleIngreso(DetalleIngresoDatos DIDatos, ref SqlConnection SqlCon, ref SqlTransaction SqlTra)
        {
            string result = "";
            try
            {
                //Establecer el Comando
                SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
                SqlCmd.Connection = SqlCon;
                SqlCmd.Transaction = SqlTra;

                SqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                SqlCmd.CommandText ="INSERT INTO tdetalleingreso (idingreso,idarticulo,preciocompra,precioventa,stockinicial,stockactual,fechaproduccion,fechavencimiento) "+
                "VALUES (@idingreso,@idarticulo,@preciocompra,@precioventa,@stockinicial,@stockactual,@fechaproduccion,@fechavencimiento)";

                SqlParameter ParIddetalle_Ingreso = new SqlParameter();
                ParIddetalle_Ingreso.ParameterName = "@idDetalleIngreso";
                ParIddetalle_Ingreso.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
                ParIddetalle_Ingreso.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                SqlCmd.Parameters.Add(ParIddetalle_Ingreso);

 
                SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idingreso", idingreso);
                SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idarticulo", idarticulo);
                SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@preciocompra", preciocompra);
                SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@precioventa", precioventa);
                SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stockinicial", stockinicial);
                SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stockactual", stockactual);
                SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fechaproduccion", fechaproduccion);
                SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fechavencimiento", fechavencimiento);

              

                result = SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1 ? "OK" : " ERROR detalleIngreso";
                Console.Write(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result = ex.Message;
            }
            return result;

        }
}}

        /****************************************
                  MEDTODO INSERTAR INGRESO 
        *****************************************/
public string cd_insertarIngreso(IngresoDatos Ingreso, List<DetalleIngresoDatos> Detalle)
 {
    string result = "";
     SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection();
     try
    {
         SqlCon.ConnectionString = ConnectionToSql.Cn;
         SqlCon.Open();
         
          //Establecer la trasacción
         SqlTransaction SqlTra = SqlCon.BeginTransaction();

         //Establecer el Comando
         SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand();

         SqlCmd.Connection = SqlCon;
         SqlCmd.Transaction = SqlTra;
         SqlCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tingreso (idempleado, idproveedor, fecha, tipocomprobante, comprobante, iva, estado) "+
         "VALUES (@idempleado,@idproveedor,@fecha,@tipocomprobante,@comprobante,@iva,@estado) SET @idIngreso=@@IDENTITY;";

         SqlParameter ParIdingreso = new SqlParameter();
         ParIdingreso.ParameterName = "@idIngreso";
         ParIdingreso.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
         ParIdingreso.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
         SqlCmd.Parameters.Add(ParIdingreso);

         SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idempleado", idempleado);
         SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idproveedor", idproveedor);
         SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha", fecha);
         SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipocomprobante", tipocomprobante);
         SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comprobante", comprobante);
         SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iva", iva);
         SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@estado", estado);
         SqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        
        result=SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1 ? "OK" : "UBRO ingresodatos ERROR";

        if (result.Equals("OK"))
        {
            //Obtener el código del ingreso generado
            Idingreso = Convert.ToInt32(SqlCmd.Parameters["@idIngreso"].Value);
            foreach (DetalleIngresoDatos det in Detalle)
            {
                det.Idingreso = Idingreso;
                //Llamar al método insertar de la clase DDetalle_Ingreso
                result = det.cd_insertarDetalleIngreso(det, ref SqlCon, ref SqlTra);
                if (!result.Equals("OK"))
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
            if(result.Equals("OK"))
            {
                SqlTra.Commit();
            }
        else
        {
            SqlTra.Rollback();
        }
    }

   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       result = ex.Message;
   }
   return result;

                  
        }}}
```

Comment: no entiendo tu pregunta... podes poner solamente lo que sea esencial a la misma? hay mucho codigo que sobra y no se distingue donde esta tu problema particular

Comment: saludos gbianchi,  `result = det.cd_insertarDetalleIngreso(det, ref command, ref transaction);`en esta parte no se como referenciar  las variables command y transaction que estan declaradas en los using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Aspectos Generales

El bloque `using` o [`using statement`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) al igual que [`using declaration`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/using#using-declaration) a partir de C# 8.0, fue creado para ahorrarnos algunas líneas de código y para garantizar la correcta liberación (`dispose`) de los recursos no administrados que son utilizados por un buen número de clases en .NET.

Como regla general, toda clase que implemente la interface `IDisposable` o `IAsyncDisposable` utiliza recursos que se deben liberar llamando al método `Dispose()`.

El bloque `using` es muy conveniente porque al compilar se encarga de insertar lo necesario para llamar al método `Dispose()` cuando corresponde, pero está limitado a que la vida del objeto no vaya más allá del método donde se crea la instancia.

En la documentación se puede leer un texto parecido a:

> Cuando el ciclo de vida de un objeto `IDisposable` está limitado a un método, debes declararlo e instanciarlo en un using statement.

### En relación a la pregunta

En vista de que las instancias de `SqlConnection` y `SqlTransaction` las necesitas como argumentos para otros métodos, tienes que utilizar un bloque [`try-finally`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-finally) o [`try-catch-finally`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch-finally). En lo personal siempre uso el `try-catch-finally`.

Al código que publicaste como "la manera que funciona" le falta muy poco para lograrlo, a continuación una guía general para estos casos: (vale destacar que no copiaré todo el código que publicaste, solo los aspectos fundamentales)

```
public string cd_insertarIngreso(IngresoDatos Ingreso, List<DetalleIngresoDatos> Detalle)
{
    //Declara las variables fuera del bloque try para que sean visibles en el finally
    SqlTransaction transaction = null;
    SqlCommand command = null;
    SqlConnection connection = null;
    //vale destacar que la conexión la puedes mantener dentro del using
    //pero lo hago de esta forma para mantener la consistencia del ejemplo

    try
    {
        //Crea las instancias dentro del try
        connection = ConnectionToSql.getConnection();
        connection.Open();
        transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
        command = new SqlCommand();

        //...
        //Todo el código que hace el trabajo
        //...
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //código que maneja la excepción
    }
    finally
    {
        //Este código siempre se ejecuta sin importar si ocurrió error o no
        //y por eso es el lugar para llamar al método Dispose() y descartar
        //cualquier recurso no administrado.

        connection?.Dispose();
        command?.Dispose();
        transaction?.Dispose();
    }
```

**Notas adicionales**:

- Vale destacar que el bloque `using` al ser compilado produce un código similar al que produce un bloque [`try-finally`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-finally)
- No es obligatorio crear las instancias dentro del bloque `try` como lo menciono en el ejemplo. Es parte de un patrón personal para aquellos objetos que al crearlos pueden producir un error.

Comment: saludos Pablo Gutiérrez, tomando en cuenta todos los aspecto técnico tienes razon,por eso q no quería dejar hacerlo así, con respecto al código así es, nunca se me ocurrio hacer las declaraciones afuera, siempre estuve dentro del try las instancias y las declaraciones. gracias me funciona todo bien ahora Que me aconsejas, como mejorar en la parte del 1er condicional xq haciendo unas pruebas en el código hago que caiga en el 2do if no captura el idingreso y hace el break del 2do condicional se detiene y no sigue, pero si agrega todo lo que se había capturado para la tabla tingreso

Answer (score 0):

Tomando en cuenta la respuesta de pablo gutierrez, el codigo me queda de esta manera,
tambien hice un cambio en el condicional. espero le ayude y lo mejore.

si hace falta algo para mejorar, bienvenido el comentario.

```
  public string cd_insertarIngreso(IngresoDatos Ingreso, List<DetalleIngresoDatos> Detalle)
    {
           //Declara las variables fuera del bloque try para que sean visibles en el finally
            SqlTransaction transaction = null;
            SqlCommand command = null;
            SqlConnection connection = null;
            //vale destacar que la conexión la puedes mantener dentro del using
            //pero lo hago de esta forma para mantener la consistencia del ejemplo
    
            string result = "";
            string result2 = "";
        try
        {
            using (connection = ConnectionToSql.getConnection())
                {
                   connection.Open();
    
                    using (transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
                    {
                        using ( command = new SqlCommand())
                        {
                            command.Connection = connection;
                            command.Transaction = transaction;
                            
                             command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tingreso (idempleado, idproveedor, fecha, tipocomprobante, comprobante, iva, estado) " +
                            "VALUES (@idempleado,@idproveedor,@fecha,@tipocomprobante,@comprobante,@iva,@estado) SET @idIngreso=@@IDENTITY;";
    
                            SqlParameter ParIdingreso = new SqlParameter();
                            ParIdingreso.ParameterName = "@idIngreso";
                            ParIdingreso.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
                            ParIdingreso.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                            command.Parameters.Add(ParIdingreso);
    
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idempleado", idempleado);
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idproveedor", idproveedor);
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha", fecha);
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipocomprobante", tipocomprobante);
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comprobante", comprobante);
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iva", iva);
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@estado", estado);
                            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    
                            result = command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1 ? "OK" : "UBRO ingresodatos ERROR";
    
                            if (result.Equals("OK"))
                            {
                                //Obtener el código del ingreso generado
                                Idingreso = Convert.ToInt32(command.Parameters["@idIngreso"].Value);
                                foreach (DetalleIngresoDatos det in Detalle)
                                {
                                    det.Idingreso = Idingreso;
                                    // Console.WriteLine(det.Idingreso);
                                    //Llamar al método insertar de la clase DDetalle_Ingreso
                                    result2 = det.cd_insertarDetalleIngreso(det, ref connection, ref transaction);
    
                                    if (!result2.Equals("OK"))
                                    {
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            if(result.Equals("OK") && result2.Equals("OK") )
                            {
                                 transaction.Commit();
                            }
                            else
 {
transaction.Rollback();
}
                         }
                  }
             }
          
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result = ex.Message;   connection.Close();
        }
                
        finally
        {
           connection.Dispose();  command.Dispose();    transaction.Dispose();
        }
        return result;
    
            }
```

Comment: No queda claro si estas publicando tu propia respuesta o si estás ampliando la pregunta. En todo caso ten en cuenta que si utilizas el código de mi ejemplo, no recomiendo crear las intancias dentro de un `using` porque te puede producir resultados inesperados además de que es completamente ineficiente. Recuerda que un `using` internamente se traduce a un `try-finally`

Comment: ok entonces dices que si lo dejo asi,no es eficiente el codigo?, seria mejor utilizar la estructura del codigo que tu compartistes y agregar los demas campos.